# Criação de arquivo txt a partir de um outro arquivo txt

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo nesse formato (o zero indica que a linha terminou):

```
-1 2 0
-2 3 0
$
-1 3 0
```

O que faço para identificar se a linha do arquivo possui um `$`? Pois tenho que implementar essa condicional para efetuar a troca de sinais dos números, que cada número (com sinal trocado) tenha sua própria linha e que cada linha deve terminar com zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leia linha por linha do arquivo e verifique com a função [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) se a linha contém o caractere desejado:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"))) {
    for(String linha; (linha = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if(linha.trim().contains("$")) {
            // A linha contém "$", fazer algo aqui...
        } else {
            // A linha não contém "$"
        }
    }
} catch (IOException err) {
    System.err.println("O arquivo nao pode ser aberto!");
    System.err.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

Para verificar se a linha termina com um sufixo, use a função [`String#endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-).